# Bootstrap-Switch and Bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I must be missing something simple. But I'm importing bootstrap 3 like so:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Which works fine. I'm then attempting to import the [bootstrap-switch](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/) using the CSS they use on their example page: http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/. Which doesn't work. What should I be importing to get the following to work:

```
<div class="make-switch switch-mini">
<input type="checkbox" checked>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for the idiots guide to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scroll down to the bottom of the page of [**bootstrap-switch**](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/)   and you will find :

```
<script src="static/js/bootstrap-switch.js"></script>
```

You have this js file missing.
They always include `js` files at the bottom of the page to reduce page load time!! :)

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer, I didn't know people did that so never thought to look at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a `bootstrap-switch.js` you have to include. You only mentioned the css. Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You missed to include the `bootstrap-swith.js`

```
<script src="static/js/bootstrap-switch.js"></script>
```